# How do I prove that the distance between two points is longer than one point in the normal and the other point in a plane?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

So, imagine $P$ is a plane with the normal $n$, and $A = (a1, a2, a3)$ is a point above the plane $P$ that does not lie on the plane. $B$ is a point collinear on the line $L$: $r = (a_1, a_2, a_3) + \lambda n$.

$C$ is a point on $P$ other than $B$.

How do I prove $\|A-C \| > \|A-B \|$ for all points $C \ne B$?

I tried drawing a diagram with points $A$ and $B$ in a line $L$ parallel to the normal, since the shortest distance from $A$ to $P$ is $L$ perpendicular. I drew a line from $B$ to $C$. Since the $L$ is parallel to the normal $n$, $L$ is perpendicular to the plane $P$.

Hence, this would be a right-angled triangle $ABC$.

Now, a hypothenuse is longer than the other two sides.

What's the best way to approach this question?

Comment: Your approach seems perfectly OK to me.

Comment: yeh - but how do I *prove* it without the values?

Comment: Allgebraicly...

Comment: You mean that $B$ is also in plane $P$? Then you should to write it.

Comment: B is where it intersects with P, which is coincidentally where the line intersects as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A} + \lambda \mathbf{n} $ for some $\lambda$.  Point $\mathbf{C}$ is in the plane and $\mathbf{C} \ne \mathbf{B}$, therefore,

$ \mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{C} - \mathbf{B}) = 0 $

Now

$ \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{C} = (\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{B}) + (\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{C}) = -\lambda \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{CB} $

It follows from this that

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
\| \mathbf{A - C} \|^2 &= (\mathbf{A - C}) \cdot (\mathbf{A - C} ) \\&= (-\lambda \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{CB} ) \cdot (-\lambda \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{CB}) \\
&= \lambda^2 \| \mathbf{n} \|^2 + \| \mathbf{CB} \|^2 \end{split} \end{equation} $

Because $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{CB} = 0 $

Therefore,

$\| \mathbf{A - C} \|^2 \gt \| \mathbf{B} - \mathbf{C} \|^2 $

because $\lambda^2 \| \mathbf{n} \|^2 \gt 0$ for $\lambda \ne 0 $

Taking the square root of both sides of the above inequality, we deduce that

$\| \mathbf{A - C} \| \gt \| \mathbf{B} - \mathbf{C} \| $

Comment: how did you do simply this? $(−λn+CB)⋅(−λn+CB)$?

Comment: I distributed the dot product, because $A \cdot (B + C) = A \cdot B + A \cdot C $

Comment: why isn't it just $λn^{2} - 2λ CB + CB ^ {2}$?

Comment: I explained that in the line that follows.

Answer (score 2):

I will write vectors A,B,C without overset arrows.

...

We want to show that $||(A-C)||>||(A-B)||$ or after squaring, we want to show that $(A-C)\bullet(A-C)> (A-B)\bullet(A-B)$. This simplifes as
$$A\bullet A-2A\bullet C+C\bullet C\overset{?}> A\bullet A-2A\bullet B+B\bullet B,$$
$$-2A\bullet C+C\bullet C\overset{?}> -2A\bullet B+B\bullet B,$$
$$2A\bullet B-2A\bullet C\overset{?}> B\bullet B-C\bullet C,$$
$$2A\bullet(B-C)\overset{?}> B\bullet B-C\bullet C.  \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, $(B-A)\perp (B-C)$, so $(B-A)\bullet(B-C)=0$ giving
$$A\bullet(B-C)=B\bullet(B-C)\tag{2}$$
Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$:
$$2B\bullet(B-C)\overset{?}> B\bullet B-C\bullet C$$
$$2B\bullet B-2B\bullet C\overset{?}> B\bullet B-C\bullet C$$
$$B\bullet B-2B\bullet C+C\bullet C\overset{?}> 0$$
$$||B-C||^2> 0$$
which is true since $C\neq B$.

Comment: what's the reason why you square it? Something to do with Pythagorean theorem or to do with the formula for the distance with two points? ie. |d| = $\sqrt{(a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2 + (c - z)^2 } $ ?

Comment: why is there a question mark $?$ over the greater than?

Also, is $(B - A) . (B-C) = 0$ the same as the cross product rule for vectors?

Comment: @Chris Is it wrong? $\cos(90)=0$? I am confused.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your working out.

Comment: Isn't this assumed? $||u||^2 > ||v||^2 <-> ||u|| > ||v||$

Comment: Yes, the norm of a vector is non-negative.

Comment: Where you show $\implies$, it's actually the reverse implication $\impliedby$ that proves the theorem. Fortunately all the inequalities are equivalent, so you could write $\impliedby$ or even $\iff$.

Comment: how did you simplify the preceding step for equation 1?

Comment: $(A - C)^{2} = A^{2} - 2AC + C^2$ ?

Comment: The question mark is because you shouldn't assume what you're proving to start. If I assume the theorem, then it is trivial to "prove" it.

Comment: @qwr The question changed.